# Where does OS X Mountain Lion store Notes data?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, apple-notes

Any idea about where OS X Mountain Lion stores Notes data? Is there a way that I can recover lost Notes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Notes are stored as HTML in an apparently non-standard binary format in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV1.storedata-wal`.

You can `grep` for known note contents on the command line, or print all notes (stored as HTML):

> `cat ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV1.storedata-wal | grep -aio '<html>.*</html>'`

---

While I was writing this answer, I also had the problem once that Notes restarted with data reset. The next launch, everything was there again, even though I had created new notes after the reset (so both the old and new notes existed on third launch). Maybe just try quitting and starting Notes again?

Comment: thanks. But it looks like the note is totally lost....

Comment: Most of my (local) notes are in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV1.storedata`.

Comment: Thank you. Presumably "wal" indicates a write-ahead log. The very first (and now probably only) time I used Notes in Mountain Lion, it ate the substantial note I composed. With your pointer I was able to recover data.

Comment: I found 'strings ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV1.storedata-wal | open -f' a useful command for recovering a lost note!

Answer (score 3):

I found this article which appears to help:
http://applehelpwriter.com/2013/03/02/how-to-recover-disappearing-notes/

```
cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes; strings NotesV1.storedata | grep body | open -f
```

Comment: Why -1 on this I wonder? I thought it was a decent article! Personally I found it easier to do a 'cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes; strings NotesV1.storedata-wal | open -f'

Answer (score 2):

On OS X Lion (10.7), I found my notes in the file below.

> ~/Library/StickiesDatabase

Comment: You're referring to Sticky Notes. However, the question is about Notes.app, the OS X version of iOS Notes.app, which was introduced in Mountain Lion and did not exist in Lion. Perhaps this should be clarified...