# Convert Mavericks' NotesV2 to Mountain Lion's NotesV1 format

Tags: macos, apple-notes

I recently reinstalled Mountain Lion after having issues with the Mavericks upgrade.

I wanted to restore the Notes from the Mavericks backup, by restoring the files mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/464679/107495):

- NotesV1.storedata
- NotesV1.storedata-shm
- NotesV1.storedata-wal

Located in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/`.

However, Mavericks seems to use a different format, called NotesV2:

- NotesV2.storedata
- NotesV2.storedata-shm
- NotesV2.storedata-wal

Is there any way I can convert these files back to the NotesV1 format to restore them under Mountain Lion?