# Where are Notes physically stored, in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, apple-notes

In OS X Lion (10.7) - Where (what file folder and pathname) are the Notes physically stored? 
Or, any tips on how I could even find the file myself, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean physically, as in the byte addresses of your hard-drive?

Comment: No not that precise.  I just need the folder and pathname of the file(s) that contain the notes, OR some tips on how to find it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does OS X Mountain Lion store Notes data?](http://superuser.com/questions/464679/where-does-os-x-mountain-lion-store-notes-data)

Answer (score 0):

Notes.app stores notes in an SQlite3 database located in

```
/Users/$USERNAME/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV2.storedata
```

and, if enabled, in an iCloud IMAP folder for sync between devices. You can view the contents of this file using the 'sqlite3' command line tool or, e.g., "SQlite Professional" from the App Store.